# Access of undefined property errors

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm getting quite a few errors after I started learning AS3 (Trying to dynamically add the crosshair to the stage instead of using mouse cursor for shooter game):

```
Main.as, Line 13 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method addChild.
Main.as, Line 13 1120: Access of undefined property crosshair.
Main.as, Line 20 1120: Access of undefined property stage.
Main.as, Line 20 1120: Access of undefined property moveCursor.
```

Answer (score 3):

You have no constructor in your class.

try this :

```
package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.ui.Mouse;
    import flash.media.Sound;
    import flash.media.SoundChannel;
    public class Main extends MovieClip {

    public var crosshair:crosshair_mc;


    public function Main()
    {
        //This creates a new instance of the cursor movie clip and adds it onto
        //the stage using the addChild method.
        crosshair = new crosshair_mc();
        addChild(crosshair);

        //Hides the default cursor on the stage so it will not be shown.
        Mouse.hide();

        //Adds an event listener onto the stage with the enter frame event which
        //repeatedly executes the moveCursor function.
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveCursor);
    }

    //This function set the x & y positions of the custom cursor to the x & y positions
    //of the default cursor.
    function moveCursor(event:Event) 
    {
      crosshair.x=mouseX;
      crosshair.y=mouseY;
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Now get `access of undefined property crosshair` on lines 30 and 31

Comment: Updated the answer again to fix that error. But please post one question per issue. If you run into another issue, post a new question.

Comment: To be clear a constructor isn't explicitly required in AS3 (it'll get made for you as an empty constructor if you leave it out).  But the answer is correct on both issues you can't have code just floating around without a function/constructor wrapping it and your variables have to be in scope (declared somewhere they're accessible).

Comment: True. However, given that I assumed this was the document class since it was named `Main`, it was clearly the largest issue. Empty constructor for your document class is getting you nowhere quickly.